# Overriding AJAX Header in WebView

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, google-chrome, webview

I am using a WebView on android. I want to override the header for AJAX requests by injecting the javascript show below.

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.realSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
var newSend = function(vData) {
    this.setRequestHeader('ClientId', 'ANDROID');
    this.setRequestHeader('CustId', '%s');
    this.realSend(vData);
            };
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = newSend;
```

I am not sure why this does not work. I have tried it on chrome directly and it did now work. When the same script is inserted into iOS/Safari it works.

Answer (score 0):

you have a syntax erro, a qute at the function end bracket   **"};**
beside that it seams to be ok , i used a similar code many times

Comment: That just came from copy pasting from android studio. But this is not working for me.